# Hex editor to open remote files

Tags: gratis, hex-viewer

I use [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) to check the HEX of files but is annoying to me to download remote files from server then open that file in the program.

Is there any HEX editor which can open remote files?

Comment: A bit meager, Cliff: what features do you need? What OS should it run on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) editor with `xxd` command, e.g.

```
vim -b +'% !xxd' http://example.com/
```

See: [How to edit binary files with Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/343/467)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I use [HxD](https://www.mh-nexus.de/en/) (the portable version).

I have just used it to open a file that is on a mapped network drive by giving the full path. I imagine that all hex editors could do that, as it is up to the operating system to resolve the path to the file.

---

[Update] I just realized that you might mean that you want to open by URL (it is unclear what you mean by “remote files”; I would normally assume those to be file son the same LAN, but YMMV). If so, you might well have trouble finding such an app.

In that case, I would advize a small batch file or Python script of just a few lines to

- Fetch the file to local temp area (using `wget`, for instance)
- Launch he hex editor, with the local temp file as parameter
- on exit from the hex editor, prompt you to upload the saved file
- Delete the local temp file
  If you don’t code, that is so simple that any code you know can do it for you quickly